# Index out of bounds (Python)

Tags: python, indexing, bounds, out

I have some data that I would like to aggregate, but I'm getting the index out of bounds error, and I can't seem to figure out why. Here's my code:

```
if period == "hour":
    n=3
    tvec_a=np.zeros([24,6])
    tvec_a[:,3]=np.arange(0,24)
    data_a=np.zeros([24,4])
elif period == "day":
    n=2
    tvec_a=np.zeros([31,6])
    tvec_a[:,2]=np.arange(1,32)
    data_a=np.zeros([31,4])
elif period == "month":
    n=1
    tvec_a=np.zeros([12,6])
    tvec_a[:,1]=np.arange(1,13)
    data_a=np.zeros([12,4])
elif period == "hour of the day":
    tvec_a=np.zeros([24,6])
    tvec_a[:,3]=np.arange(0,24)
    data_a=np.zeros([24,4])
i=0
if period == "hour" or period == "day" or period == "month":
    while i <= np.size(tvec[:,0]):
        data_a[tvec[i,n],:]=data_a[tvec[i,n],:]+data[i,:]
        i=i+1
        if i > np.size(tvec[:,0]):
            break
```

I only get the error if I make period day or month. Hour works just fine.
(The code is part of a function that takes in a tvec, data and period)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-7fb910c0f29b>", line 1, in <module>
    aggregate_measurements(tvec,data,"month")

  File "C:/Users/Julie/Documents/DTU - design og innovation/4. semester/Introduktion til programmering og databehandling (Python)/Projekt 2 electricity/agg_meas.py", line 33, in aggregate_measurements
    data_a[tvec[i,n],:]=data_a[tvec[i,n],:]+data[i,:]

IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 12
```

EDIT: Fixed it, by writing minus 1 on the value from the tvec:

```
data_a[tvec[i,n]-1,:]=data_a[tvec[i,n]-1,:]+data[i,:]
```

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: I think `data_a[tvec[i,n],:]=data_a[tvec[i,n],:]+data[i,:]` is where you get the error, could you try printing `tvec[i,n]` value before that line in your while ?

Comment: Mmmh try replacing `<=` with `<` in your while ? **Edit** ha! @Karin answered this also

Comment: *'Fixed it, by writing minus 1'*: This hasn't fixed it, just stopped it crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Since lists are 0-indexed, you can only go up to index 11 on a 12-element array.

Therefore `while i <= np.size(tvec[:,0])` should probably be `while i < np.size(tvec[:,0])`.

Extra Note: The `break` is unnecessary because the while loop will stop once the condition is met anyway.